# Live Video Streaming server available for testing

Tags: video

I am doing test using Android to play live streaming.  Did some search here and only able to find the following :

"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"

Anyone knows any other open public server available can be used for testing without signup ?

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention the streaming format you want to use but here are some examples of the most popular ones:

MPEG-DASH test stream:

- https://livesim.dashif.org/livesim/ato_10/testpic_2s/Manifest.mpd (DASF IF test stream, tested and working March 2020 - check for others at the latest version of the client here: https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/

HLS test stream:

- https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/basic-stream.html

Smoothstreaming test streams:

- http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/

Update: Answering the question in the comment about m3u8 live streams:

Different Android versions support different media packaging, codecs etc - for your case you want to take a look at the 'HTTP/HTTPS live streaming' (i.e.HLS) heading in the Android Media Format support page:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

This will show you which version of HLS is supported depending on the version of Android. Its worth checking with your specific device also as different devices support different formats and codec variants, profiles etc.

For a longer list of HLS links, which seems to be pretty up to date and which includes live streams, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265943/334402.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  What I am looking for is Live Stream which can be supported by Android "VideoView" class.  I know it support the "m3u8" but don't know which IPTV server is free to test this.

Comment: @dilbert - Answer updated with link which includes live HLS streams. You need to check your particular target devices will support them.